# Do I need the factory to obtain the service in a plugin?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

The code I'm using in my plugins looks like this.

```csharp
IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory =
  (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(
    typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory
  .CreateOrganizationService(Context.UserId);
```

I wonder if it's not sufficient to use this syntax to obtain my service.

```csharp
IOrganizationService service = 
  serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationService));
```

Comment: Does your second syntax work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this syntax most (all) of the time.

```csharp
IOrganizationService service = provider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationService));
```

However, the factory approach might be recommended. I'm not certain how CRM's SDK handles things but generally, a factory is a static class that produces the objects for you. That way, there's more functionality (possibly) that will make your programming life easier (or more confusing).

It's my understanding that both syntaxes work in CRM and, unless you hit some really weird scenario, it's your pick.

Comment: that will always return null as IOrganizationService is not a valid lookup on IServiceProvider. You have to get it from the factory

Comment: @doodlleus I'm not sure you'r eright. I haven't been in CRM for a while so I can't test but if I recal correctly, that's the precise line I've used. Are you certain it's not a difference in CRM On-line? Or CRM 2013/2015? I see the question's a bit dated...

Answer (score 4):

Your question has caused me to look at my Plugin `IOrganizationService` creation.  I wrote three extension methods to make my life easier, and one of them uses the factory method, and one doesn't (although it passes in the plugin execution context).  These methods have all been working in production for a while now.  I'm just not sure why I use the factory service, for one method, and not for the other.

```c#
public static IPluginExecutionContext GetContext(this IServiceProvider provider)
{
    return (IPluginExecutionContext) provider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
}

public static IOrganizationService GetService(this IServiceProvider provider, IPluginExecutionContext context)
{
    return provider.GetService(context, context.UserId);
}

public static IOrganizationService GetService(this IServiceProvider provider, IPluginExecutionContext context, Guid impersonationUser)
{
    var serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)provider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
    return serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(impersonationUser);
}
```

### Edit

Commenter has pointed out that the second method calls the third, and in this manner, both methods are using the factory to create the service.

Comment: You're ALWAYS using the factory to get the Service. The second method delegates to the third method, it just provides the user to impersonate from the context.

Comment: This is the correct approach to solving the questioner's core complaint that the beginning few lines of a plugin are "messy."

Here is a solution developed by a colleague of mine that I find to be very useful to both set up the plugins and validate that they are registered on the correct message & have the expected images registered to them. Vastly improves code readability & quality.

http://www.procentrix.com/Community/NickN/archive/2012/08/10/crm-2011-abstracting-plugin-setup.aspx

Comment: @MichaelBlackburn Thanks. I recognize your Nick from the XRM Prep Plug-in.  We do something very similar.  Instead of having a separate class to populate and maintain, we have a base class that populates simliar properties for us.  Removes the need for p.Context and the like.